# PHP to SQL on-change not updating

Tags: php, mysql, html, codeigniter

I have a fairly general problem. I have a small form

```
    <form action="<?=base_url();?>ticket/close_ticket/<?=$ticket_details['id'];?>" method="post" id="close_ticket" name="close_ticket">
        <ul>
            <li><label for="frm_status">Status<span class="req">*</span></label>
                <span class="input">                        
                    <select id="frm_status" name="status" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                            <option value="<? if ($ticket_details['status'] == "Open") $status= "1"; else $status= "2"; echo $status;?>"><? if ($ticket_details['status'] == "Open") $status= "Open"; else $status= "Closed"; echo $status;?></option>
                            <option value="<? if ($ticket_details['status'] == "Open") $status= "2"; else $status= "1"; echo $status;?>"><? if ($ticket_details['status'] == "Open") $status= "Closed"; else $status= "Open"; echo $status;?></option>                  
                    </select>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </form>
```

This form contains the drop list option box, that on change submits the form to the close ticket controller......

```
      public function close_ticket()
  {
    $this->load->model('ticket_model');
    $ticket_id = mysql_real_escape_string($this->uri->segment(3));

    if($_POST)
    {
        //save ticket
        unset ($_POST['id']);
        $_POST['id'] = $ticket_id;
        $this->ticket_model->close_ticket($_POST);

        redirect(base_url().'ticket/edit/'.$ticket_id.'/');
        return;

    }
    redirect(base_url().'ticket/edit/'.$ticket_id.'/');
  }
```

which it does. This controller is to post the information to the model to update the SQL.....

```
    public function close_ticket($ticket_post)
{
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM ".$this->tables_ticket." WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($ticket_post['id'])."';");

if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
        $row = $query->row();
        $query = $this->db->query("UPDATE ".$this->tables_ticket."
                                    SET
                                    status = '".mysql_real_escape_string($ticket_post['status'])."'
                                    WHERE
                                    id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($ticket_post['id'])."'
                                    ");
        }
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

then after all this, redirect back to the form. I am assuming that on redirect the form will then populate the drop list with the updated data. This is where I am struggling, as It sends the changed data, and somewhere it is not registering the change and returning the page, unchanged. 
Question, would this work with a confirmation/secondary submission page, followed by redirect, and is it that I am trying to return the changed data in the same function where it is failing?

```
    $body_data['ticket_list']       = $this->ticket_model->list_ticket();
    $body_data['ticket_details']    = $this->ticket_model->get_ticket($ticket_id);
    $body_data['ticket_summary']    = $this->ticket_model->list_ticket_summary($ticket_id);
    $body_data['customer_list']     = $this->ticket_model->get_customer_details($ticket_id);
    $body_data['precan_list']       = $this->ticket_model->list_messages();
    $body_data['users_list']        = $this->ticket_model->list_users();

    $foot_data['accordian_active'] = 5;

    $this->load->view('head',$head_data);
    $this->load->view('sidebar/service',$head_data);
    $this->load->view('ticket/edit',$body_data);
    $this->load->view('foot',$foot_data);
    return;
```

The edit function simply returns a range of population query lists.
unless i need a new query to repopulate the ticket_details list?

Comment: can you post your ticket/edit controller/function - i think the error is in there. I would guess you are not reloading the new $ticket_details after the update.

Comment: the edit function that is being redirected too is mainly acting as the view in this instance as this contains several functions that loads all sorts of information. Am i following your correctly....I have the $ticket_details populating the list but on change im gonna need a new query populating $updated_ticket_details for example? ill post the edit function.

Comment: so if you do a var_dump on $body_data BEFORE you do the load view - does it show the updated ticket?

Comment: I see. no, whats not happening is it is not posting it would seem. As i have numerous other functions similar to that posted that work, can i assume it is a html error?

Comment: maybe its a caching issue? i.e. its caching the old page, and not showing the new one?

Comment: i think thats what may been happening. how can this be avoided?? although presumably the data should still be being sent to the DB in this case. which it isn't....